# How does Grails make `params` available to a Singleton controller? (Grails internals)

Tags: grails, groovy, singleton, metaprogramming

If I make a Grails controller a singleton via:

```
static scope = "singleton"
```

... how does Grails expose a `params` variable to my controller's actions, where the `params` are request specific?

I would understand if `params` were passed into my action methods as a variable, but here `params` are just available and in-scope (and different for simultaneous  requests, despite the fact that there's only one instance of my controller).

**How is this implemented under the hood?**

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Each request gets its own thread, so the request, response, params, session, etc. are available independent of whether the controller is a singleton or created new for every request. It would be different if these variables were fields in the class, but they're not.

Under the hood this is implemented by an AST transform that mixes in `org.codehaus.groovy.grails.plugins.web.api.ControllersApi` into the controller classes, which adds methods such as `getParams()` (which you can use as the `params` property). These call `RequestContextHolder.currentRequestAttributes()` to get the thread-local information.

Comment: Burt, so if we have a singleton scoped controller with 4 methods, let's say one of the methods upload a file to a singleton service and return the name of the uploaded file, if several concurrent users access this controller action at the same time, this should be safe, am I correct ?

Comment: Whether the instances are singletons or not has no bearing - as long as the instances have no shared mutable state, or at a minimum the methods you call don't access mutable state (read or write), then there will be no concurrency issues.

Comment: What you mean is, if I'm writing a file to disk in a method, e.g def uploadPhoto(), then multiple users calling that method can cause issue ? I'm sorry but I'm a bit confused :(

Comment: When you enter a method you get your own copy of local variables. As long as you don't access anything that's shared, all is good. And if you write a file, as long as the filename is unique there shouldn't be issues there.

Comment: Got it :) Thanks Burt, Your comment was very helpful.